# How to check an ArrayList until deepest position?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a mainclass Item and the subclasses BundleItem, ProductItem and also a class Order.

The order class creates an ArrayList list where Items can be added.
BundleItem also creates an ArrayList bundle where Items can be added (a Bundle of Items with discount)

The method (twice once in order and BundleItem)

```
addItem(Item item) {
list.add(item) ///for order
bundle.add(item) ///for bundle
}
```

So a bundle can contain an other bundle, but the problem begins if a bundle contains itself indirectly like

```
bundle1.addItem(bundle1);
```

Because if I use the a getTotalPrice() or print method the program crashes because of endlesslyness bundle1 (bundle1 in bundle1 in bundle1 etc. (sorry forgot the word))

What I did is check if the item is already in the bundle and only add if false

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    for (Item position:bundle) {
        if (position == item) {
            System.out.println("You cannot put the same bundle in itself!");
        } else {
            bundle.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not enough... because bundle1 can contain bundle 2 and bundle2 contain bundle1 too what lead to the same problem...
So how can I expand the code so that if the position is a BundleItem it goes deeper and make the check there too?

Thank you very much for your help!

Kind regards
Akagex

Comment: You are looking for a recursion.

Comment: Use equals instead of ==

Comment: thanks I'll fix that and yes the word I was looking for was recursion :)

Comment: Could you give a minimal and verifiable example so that we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, I think I have a basic representation of what you'd want to do.

I pseudocoded it out for you, but basically, without being able to reproduce your specific problem, you'd want something like this, probably (there's going to be a bunch of ways to do this, this is just what I whipped up)

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    //if it's the same then that's bad right?
    boolean isSame = isItself(bundle, item);
    if (isSame) {
        System.out.println("You cannot put the same bundle in itself!");
    } else {
        bundle.add(item);
    }
}

private boolean isItself(bundle, item){
    //Check each item in the bundle
    for (Object position:bundle) {
        //If it matches itself then return true, it's itself.
        if(position.equals(item)){
            return true;
        }
        //If it's a bundle item then recurse down to see if it matches itself
        if(position instanceof BundleItem){
            return isItself(position, item);
        }
    }
    //once everything has been checked, it nothing matches and we've gone down as far as we can go, then return false
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The idea is very good and looks like it could work because of the "instanceof" but the problem is they type of bundle and position are not the same, or do I see this wrong, this is the error I'm getting while programming :/ Or which time must Bundle and position be?

Comment: I'm a little hazy on my Object typing/Parent typing, but I think this would be ok, but I will edit the code regardless since the change should work.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a method in BundleItem which checks its own items. I suggest reading a bit about [Recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function). They're lots of fun!

Here's an example of the method you could create inside BundleItem.

```
public boolean addBundle(Bundle bundle2) {
    if (bundle2 == this) {
        return false;
    }

    if (bundle2 == null) {
        this.bundle2 = bundle2;
    } else {
        bundle2.addBundle(bundle2);
    }ﬁ

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how can I use this method recursive to fix my Problem? Because if would check it's own like the for statement and would not go deeper into inside, or do I understand it wrong?
How can I use this method recursive then?

Comment: @Akagex I added an example of the method I was talking about. This method will return true when you've added a bundle to the bundle, but returns false if you try to add Bundle1 to Bundle1. I hope this answer is satisfying!